# can i change switch my Next version from 12.1.1.canary to 12.1.0?

Tags: next.js

> Hi,  i am working on a Next.js project that i have not intialized
> myself. The developper before me created the application before i
> came.
>
> So, the version is next@12.1.1-canary.7
>
> even the name seems odd to me, can i relatively safely change the
> version to something like next@12.1.0 ? Because sometimes there are
> npm packages i cannot use because of this canary version.
>
> Can someone explain to me what this canary version is ? is it an
> unstable test version ? Thank you !

Comment: The Next.js canary versions are pre-release versions. Whether you can safely switch the version back to the previous stable release version depends entirely on your codebase. Best way for you to find out is to test it yourself.

Comment: yes this is what i thought, i'll try ti and see, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`npm install next@12.1.0`